# ProgrammingError: relation does not exist

Tags: python, django

На запрос списка постов (PostListView) django выдает такую ошибку, помогите, пожалуйста исправить.

**post_list.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="new-post container">
        <span>Новый пост</span>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
    </a><br><br>
    {% for post in post_list %}
        <h3>{{ post.author }} - {{ post.date }}</h3>
        <p><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.text }}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">Добавить пост</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    template_name = "blog/post_list.html"
```

Comment: Очевидно, вы не применили [миграции](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо, понял